# A class has 1000 students. 900 are Computer Science students. 200 are Math students. How many are Computer Science Math Dual major students?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

My professor asked this stupid question on an exam. Would you say that the answer is

a. 100 Students, or 
b. Not enough information to tell

This is more of a precision of English language question than a partitioning question.

I was so confused because it doesn't say anywhere that CS union Math is 1000. Which one is reasonable to assume from reading this problem.

Thanks

Comment: You are correct that as written it is ambiguous.  If it were told that every student in the class is at least one of math or computer science, only then could we precisely say.  Without that information, all we can tell is that it is some number between $100$ and $200$ that are dual major math/compsci.

Comment: Yes. The question was worded exactly as I have shown it.

There are 1000 students. 900 of them are Computer Science, 200 are math. How many are CS Math duals.

Comment: Exactly ... so b.  Seems like you answered your own question ....

Answer (score 4):

Between 100 and 200.
Of course, not enough info to tell the precise number.